# Bill me later in the shopping cart itself

Tags: asp.net, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a requirement where i have to integrate BILL ME LATER feature into our cart. But the problem is we required some scenario where  customer add products to cart and he will have three options 
1. Regular checkout
2. Paypal CheckOut
3 BILL ME LATER Option

Is it possible to have it like this i mean enable this before going to paypal ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have bill me later alone in your shopping cart.
But in Express Checkout you can force this option: check [**here**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) but not before going to paypal

[image]